# What's the point of these weird spam emails

Tags: email, spam, phishing

I've been recently receiving a lot of SPAM emails that make no sense. There is content of one of them:

```
"State authorities say they have arrested a suspect in the deadly shooting of five people, 
almost 24 hours after a gunman opened fire in a crowded mall on . Washington State Patrol 
confirmed the capture in a tweet. The 20-year-old suspect was taken into custody in Oak 
Harbor, about 30 miles west of the crime scene in Burlington, a small town north of Seattle. 
A press conference is set for 9:30 Eastern time night.In the 1970s, struggling actress 
Jamie Lee Curtis landed the role of Laurie Strode in the seminal horror movie Halloween. 
Since then, she's starred in dozens of movies (True Lies and Freaky to name a few) and 
managed to become a best-selling author and a member of the House of Lords. It just goes to 
show: If you don't get stabbed to death in the first hour, you'll do great! In the late 
1980s, Curtis filed a patent for a diaper/baby wipe combo, so we've invited her to play a 
game called "Eureka!" Three questions about inventors and their inventions. Dear Sugar 
Radio is a weekly podcast from member station WBUR. Hosts Steve Ald and Cheryl Strayed 
offer "radical empathy" and advice on everything from relationships and parenthood to 
dealing with drug problems or anxiety."
```

And so It goes on with a wall of text which looks like it was combined from several internet articles. Interesting thing is that those email come in both english and somewhat polish translated version (It looks like it was translated by google translate). I'm pole and the email is registered in polish domain.

Those emails contain no hyperlinks, no attachments, and no way to put me in interaction which could possibly achieve anything compromising security of my data, It's just plain wall of meaningless text.

What can be point of spamming me with such emails? Is it a common occurence or am I just being trolled by somebody?